# javascript alert show only first 25 line

Tags: javascript, php, output, alert

i have this output string to generate an Alert with tree variable.

```
echo <script language="javascript"> alert("array (\n  'SIS' => \n  array (\n    'MEMORYUSAGE' => \n    array (\n      'STANDBY' => '1.01',\n      'STANDBYTXT' => '1.01 Mb',\n      'LASTRUN' => '1.01',\n      'RUNNING' => 0.0,\n      'RUNNINGTXT' => '0 Mb',\n    ),\n    'EXECTIMEUSAGE' => \n    array (\n      'STANDBY' => -1547742337.322018,\n      'LASTRUN' => 0.0007879734039306641,\n      'RUNNINGTXT' => 'Menos de 1 Seg',\n    ),\n  ),\n)\narray (\n  'SES_START' => true,\n  'SES_TIMEOUT' => 1547767410,\n  'SES_ACTIVITY' => 1547745937,\n  'SES_LANG' => 'es_ES',\n  'HOME' => 2,\n)\n") </script>
```

the problem is that alert is cutting the last line, and i dont know wath this happend or hoe to prevent this.

instead of show this:

```
'HOME' => 2
```

Show it `"..."` three points.

Comment: What browser? It works fine in Firefox for me.

Comment: That's probably browser-dependent, some browsers show all the text and scrollbar if needed, some browsers truncate the text to fit in the alert window. Use browser console for debugging.

Comment: Google chrome up to date...

Comment: Sounds like you may want to move to a custom dialog and not an alert to display data.

Comment: @FranciscoNúñez Sounds like Chrome has a limit to how much it'll display, then. You probably can't do anything about it with `alert()` - you'll probably need to make your own custom alerts. Something like https://sweetalert2.github.io/ perhaps.

Comment: @epascarello any way to override or rewrite this Limite??

Comment: @FranciscoNúñez No, there's probably not going to be a way to override the limit in Chrome.

Comment: `alert` is really not meant to dump a page of text in front of the user. You should render something to to the body of the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Until now:
after a while looking for a solution to this; It seems that there is no way to work what I indicate with google chrome.

The united solution is to change the alert () by a custom div or modal.

In a while I will return to this topic.